# Accessing a property in a class method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I think the question is self explanatory.
If I declare a property of a class, I don't seem to able to access that property within a class method. Is there any way to do this? The conventional method would usually be:
self.[property]
But when I call it within a class method, the compiler hands me a syntax error.

Comment: Properties are members of INSTANCES.

Comment: Some code could be helpful. And see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771709

Comment: A property of a class... please show some code with what you mean by that. I assume you really mean a property of instances of a class, in which case you can't access from a class method as, well, there is no instance within that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access property from a class method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771709/access-property-from-a-class-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's not a property of the class but rather a property of each object that is created using that class as a template.  To get to the property, you need an instance of the class.  One frequent path to this is to use a **Singleton pattern** so that you have an object and a way of implementing class methods that affect that object.